# Does Dr Doom ever question his existence?

Tags: marvel, dr-doom

I was reading about "What if #52" about how Dr. Doom's armor can brainwash whoever wears it and make them believe they are the real Victor von Doom, and I had a small memory that there were other times it happened. The thing is, did it happen in any of the comics or media that he questioned his own existence? Asking himself if he is the real Victor von Doom or just a clone/brainwashed person wearing the armor of Dr. Doom?

I'm not really sure about the exact form of brainwashing the Doom armor uses or the technology shenanigans about how it happens, but I'm curious if it happened. Unless the wearer is brainwashed to never suspect, not think about it, or even remember that his own armor can brainwash people. Not sure if the armor gave him memories or just changed his personality as it could even have given him some memory holes every time Doom tries to remember something from the past.

Comment: Given Doom's massive (and largely justified) superiority complex, it's unlikely he'd question that he's the real Doom.

Comment: When multiple characters who believe they are the real Doom come into conflict, the one that eventually wins is the real Doom, regardless of what the characters, (or the writers) may have thought at the time.

Comment: At least once everybody has an existential crisis, he must have had one too